# Angular architecture for huge page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, controller

I need create one huge page on AngularJS. And I'm thinking which architecture is better for this page? So, page has 3 blocks with a lot functionality, but the main is: left block has accounts, user can pick some account and this account should be shown on center block. Center block can be changed and result should be shown on the right block.
For html I created 3 views for each block and included them with ng-include. Also I want somehow divide controller for few files, because I didn't work with a lot of code in one file. And I see a few ways, how to do this.
1. Create controller for each view, and transfer data by broadcast, or save data on RootScope and use watchers.
2. Create parent controller and transfer data by him.
What do you think about this? Or maybe one big controller is the best solution for this? And what is the best way for transferring data through controllers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches for your situation, I'll tell you what I think is best

First of all, you make an parent abstract state where you can do all your dirty work in it, wither it was getting data from server or otherwise, inject all the data you need to use in `$scope` and then go to the child state "where your big page is"

something like that :

```
.state('parent_state', {
    url: '/home',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'whatever',
    controller: 'yourCtrl as yourCtrl'
  })
  .state("parent_state.child",{
    //Whatever you need here
  })
```

when you go to your child state you will have all the data you need in `$scope` , so you can focus more on logic instead of wrapping data

from my opinion, a page should have only one controller, there is no point if giving a controller to every portion of your view, else you need to go with custom directives

So if you have one controller that rules them all, or one controller and multiple directives.

your call